# Generate random integer between two ranges

Tags: python, python-2.7, random

I want to get a random number between (65, 90) and (97, 122) range. I can select random number in range using

```
import random
random.randint(65,95)
```

but ˋrandint` take the only integer so how can I do?? any idea

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could generate 2 ranges, and then a `random.choice([first range rand, second range rand])`

Comment: `i = randint(65, 115); i += 7 if i > 90 else 0`

Comment: Are you sure you're not really after `random.choice(string.ascii_letters)` ?

Comment: @JonClements XY problem solved :)

Comment: @JonClements rather `ord(random.choice(...))`

Comment: what John means is that the code is probably used to generate letters, ASCII codes are probably not that interesting.

Comment: @Kallz maybe [edit] your question: what do you want to do with this number. Because Jon Clements comment is a very good suggestion.

Comment: @JonClements yes, that's exactly I want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def random_of_ranges(*ranges):
  all_ranges = sum(ranges, [])
  return random.choice(all_ranges)

print(random_of_ranges(range(65, 90), range(97, 122)))
```

This is a very general way of handling this.  You can pass any number of ranges (or subset of them).  But it is rather costly, especially for very large sets (like `range(1, 100000000)`).  For your usecase (and maybe several others in the vicinity) it would be sufficient, though.

Comment: Why would you build `all_ranges` here? `random.choice(random.choice(ranges))` does the same without rebuilding a list each time...

Comment: It does the same if all ranges are of equal size (which is the case in the Q above).  In the general case this need not be true, and `choice(choice([ range(1, 100), range(200, 202) ]))` will return 200 and 201 way more often than e. g. 50 or 37.  But of course, building the list just once and then use it in all calls with this input would be a good optimization.

Comment: Good point - well made :)

Comment: I have a feeling it's going to be slower, but...: `heapq.nlargest(1, itertools.chain(ranges), key=lambda L: random.random())` :p

Comment: Why using `nlargest` instead of `max`?

Comment: Just to make my non-serious suggestion more obviously non-serious?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
def random():
  arr1 = np.random.randint(65,90)
  arr2 = np.random.randint(97,122)
  out = np.stack((arr1,arr2))
  out = np.random.choice(out)
  return out
```

Answer (score -1):

Make your own?

```
import random

def my_rand():
  numbers = list()
  numbers.append(random.randint(65,95))
  numbers.append(random.randint(97,122))
  return numbers[random.randint(0,1)]
```

Comment: That's not what is probably wanted if the ranges are of different size.

Comment: plus the code has a syntax error.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre fixed, thanks for taking the time to complain instead of fixing it ;)

Comment: @Alfe assumption

Comment: @Nicoretti No.  Not assumption.  Comment.  _You_ assumed something about the wanted distribution and implemented a function based on your assumption (without any declaration of the assumption).  I _commented_ that this might _probably_ not be what PO wants.  Without any more information from PO that statement about the probability is not an assumption, it's a fact.

Comment: @Nicoretti I would have fixed it if it wasn't already downvoted. I figured it wasn't worth the trouble.